# Bootstrap Datepicker - daysofweekdisabled only range day

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, configuration, datepicker

I have a problem with Bootstrap Datepicker.

The datepicker is configured using the following code:

```
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
        locale: 'it',
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: '06/30/2016',
        maxDate:'06/06/2016'     
    });
```

But other period, all day are clickable.

I ask Help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Could you clarify what you mean by "*But other period, all day are clickable*?"

Comment: Please, try to explain better your problem

Answer (score 0):

Example
from 01/01/2015 to 15/06/2015 all day available to click
from 16/06/2015 to 31/12/2005 only saturday available to click